# How to simplify 3 variables with 2 equations?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

There are 2 equations of 3 variables and I have simplified and eliminated the third varibale to ge the relationship of the first and the second variable. Codes are as this:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
equa1 = \[Mu] == 1.3333333333333334`*^-6 + 1.2`/H;
equa2 = H == B/\[Mu];
Solve[Eliminate[{equa1, equa2}, {H}], \[Mu]]
```

The hint is

> Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The 
> answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and 
> numericizing the result.

But when I change to

```
Solve[Eliminate[{equa1, equa2}, {H}], B]
```

Then it is normal, so why?

Comment: Try: `equa1 = \[Mu] == Rationalize[1.3333333333333334`*^-6 + 1.2`/H, 0];` `Solve` likes exact numbers.

Comment: This is no error, only a warning. MMA rationalized your machine numbers for the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example,we need not use `Eliminate`,using `{μ}, {H}` in `Solve` to solve `{μ}` and at the same time eliminate `{H}`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
equa1 = μ == 1.3333333333333334`*^-6 + 1.2`/H;
equa2 = H == B/μ;
Solve[Rationalize[{equa1, equa2}, 0], {μ}, {H}]
```

[image]